# I'm trying to adapt the code for when the searched item is not found

Tags: excel, vba, search, error-handling

I have this code that searches a separate workbook, on a particular sheet and gives me the data in the next cell of what I have searched. This works fine if the searched item is found but I can't seem to adapt the code if the searched item is not found. When this happens I just want to return a message to the label on the user form that the item is not found. I have watched and read tutorials and tried using ***If Not Is Nothing*** but I just can't seem to get it to work.
I'd be grateful if someone could help? Many thanks.

```
Dim departments As Workbook
Dim searchItem As String
Dim foundItem As String


Set departments = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MyPc\Desktop\Department References.xls")

searchItem = UserForm1.Textbox1.Value

If Menu.optionBtnDepartmentOne = True Then
foundItem = departments.Worksheets("Department One").Range("D2:D10000").Find(searchItem).Offset(0, 1).Value

ElseIf Menu.optionBtnDepartmentTwo = True Then
foundItem = departments.Worksheets("Department Two").Range("D2:D10000").Find(searchItem).Offset(0, 1).Value

ElseIf Menu.optionBtnDepartmentThree = True Then
foundItem = departments.Worksheets("Department Three").Range("D2:D10000").Find(searchItem).Offset(0, 1).Value

End If

UserForm1.Label = foundItem
Workbooks("Department References").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: you cannot return the value of `Nothing` remove all the `.Value` from your finds.  Declare `foundItem` as a `Range` not a `String`  Then you can test, `If not foundItem is nothing then` before trying to assign it to the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thougth of writing it as a function? And if the function returns "something" then there is the message you wanted. So it would look like this:

```
Sub fill_UF()

Dim searchItem as string

SearchItem = UserForm1.Textbox1.Value

If foundItem(searchItem)= "Did not Find item" then 
Msgbox foundItem(searchItem)
goto ending
End if

UserForm1.Label = foundItem(searchItem)

ending:
End sub
```

'

```
Function foundItem(searchItem as string)

Dim departments As Workbook
'Dim searchItem As String
'Dim foundItem As String


Set departments = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MyPc\Desktop\Department References.xls")

'searchItem = Cstr(searchItem) ' sometimes you need to add this

If Menu.optionBtnDepartmentOne = True Then
foundItem = departments.Worksheets("Department One").Range("D2:D10000").Find(searchItem).Offset(0, 1).Value
Goto ending

ElseIf Menu.optionBtnDepartmentTwo = True Then
foundItem = departments.Worksheets("Department Two").Range("D2:D10000").Find(searchItem).Offset(0, 1).Value
Goto ending

ElseIf Menu.optionBtnDepartmentThree = True Then
foundItem = departments.Worksheets("Department Three").Range("D2:D10000").Find(searchItem).Offset(0, 1).Value
Goto ending
End If

foundItem = "Did not Find item"

ending:
Workbooks("Department References").Close SaveChanges:=False

End function
```

Try this. 
It might need some editing to work, but the idea is there.